# Applescript: How to create new folder from file name, create subfolders, move file into subfolder

Tags: macos, directory, applescript

I would like to create an **applescript application** that I can drag a file (such as an Illustrator file in my case) onto in order to create a **new folder** with the name of the **original** (Illustrator) **file**. I want that new folder to be created in the **same location** as the Illustrator file.

Next, I want to create 3 **subfolders** within my new folder. (Ex. One with the name of ff, one named mr, and one name NX.)

Within one of the created subfolders, I want another subfolder created. (Ex. named Hires, inside the ff folder.)

Finally, I want the illustrator file to be **moved** into the (mr) subfolder that was created.

Below is a screen shot of the file structure that I would like to create.

[Desired file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENSI4.png)

I have been messing around with some different scripts but haven't gotten anything to work as desired.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution taking advantage of the `mkdir` shell command which is able to create complex folder structures in one line.

Save the script as application

```
on open theFiles
    set folderStructure to "/{ff/Hires,mr,NX}"
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        tell application "System Events"
            set {name:Nm, name extension:Ex} to aFile
            set baseFileName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & Ex in Nm) - 1) of Nm
            set baseFolder to POSIX path of container of aFile & "/" & baseFileName
        end tell
        do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of baseFolder & folderStructure
        do shell script "/bin/mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of aFile & space & quoted form of (baseFolder & "/mr")
    end repeat
end open
```

Comment: Works great. However, there is one more thing I want it to do. I would like all the folders created (ff/Hires,mr,NX) to all be contained in a new folder **named after** the file that I dumped on the application. Thanks. @vadian

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks Much!